# Question about retaining mixed plex when converting from PS to PDF

Tags: ghostscript

Good day,

We print Postscript files directly on industrial Xerox printers.

One client's Postscript files were getting garbled due to a font issue that I was unable to track down, so I used Adobe's Distiller to convert from PS to PDF. The same font issues turned up in the PDFs that were generated from Distiller. No amount of option tweaking helped me out, and find/replace font operations using the Callas pdfToolbox didn't work out for me.

So, I downloaded Ghostscript and spent an entertaining hour remembering how DOS worked. I was eventually able to convert several PS files into flawless-looking PDFs by going to the Ghostscript directory and doing this:

gswin64 -dQUIET -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=myoutputfilename.pdf myinputfilename.ps

But, I didn't think things all the way through because now I'm faced with the problem of mixed-plex. Some of the documents in the file are one-page documents and some are two-page documents, which should be printed duplex.

PS handles all of this for us when we put it on one of the Xerox printers. PDF, of course, does not. I can only specify simplex or duplex on the printer - so it's either one or the other, which doesn't work for a PDF with both.

Is there any clean, (or dirty), way to get around this? I was thinking of somehow instructing Ghostscript to insert blank pages after every simplex page of a PS file, and then just printing the entire PDF duplex, but have no idea how I would begin to do this.

Any assistance greatly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

It 'sounds like' you have concatenated several PostScript program together here, is that the case ?

This isn't really a great idea, it can lead to incorrect output, I wonder if this is the source of your problem with Distiller and your printer.

Have you tried producing PostScript instead of PDF, by using the ps2write device instead of pdfwrite ? While this won't carry any of the device-specific controls (such as /Duplex), you can easily put them back. In fact recent versions of the device will allow you to specify code to be inserted at document and/or page level.

Comment: Hi Ken, thank you for your reply.

What we get from the client are PostScript files. When printed on a Xerox iGen printer, these PS files produce garbage - bad font placement, garbled text, and such.

If I use Acrobat Distiller to make a PDF, the garbage is still apparent in the PDF.

If I use Ghostscript to make a PDF, the garbage is gone - the PDF is clean and readable.

However, the PDF loses the Duplex/Simplex stuff because of the nature of PDF versus PS.

You're saying that I can use ps2write instead of pdfwrite to produce a PDF that includes Duplex information and such?

Comment: No... I'm saying that you **might** be able to use ps2write to produce **PostScript** files from the input PostScript files. Since the process of converting to PDF 'corrects' the problem (and without seeing one of the files I can't guess why that would happen) its possible that the ps2write device (which does a very similar process) might also 'fix' the problems. In this case it would produce PostScript output, which you could then easily customise with the Duplex setting. If you know in advance which are which, you can even have the ps2write device include that for you in the output PS file.

Comment: Hah! You're right - If I use ps2write to produce a PostScript file from the original PostScript file, it gets rid of the garbled font problem. I don't know how or why it works, but it does. :)

I'm still having the simplex/duplex issue. My Xerox iGen printer doesn't recognize that some are duplex and some are simplex - I'm guessing that the original code or tags or whatever in the PS file is getting discarded somehow somewhere in the ps2write process.

Comment: I tried using the -dDUPLEX switch in the command line and there was no improvement. My current call is:

gswin64 -dQUIET -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dDUPLEX -sDEVICE=ps2write -sOutputFile=outputfile.ps inputfile.ps

Comment: -dDUPPLEX won't help you with the ps2write device. If you want to control what gets emitted for device control then you need to look at the documentation on PSDocOptions and PSPageOptions https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.25/VectorDevices.htm#PS

Comment: Thank you again. :)

Yikes. It looks like I'm in over my head. Trying to carry over this one feature from my old PostScript to my new PostScript generated with ps2write looks like it would require a lot more experience with PostScript than I have.

I got as far as being able to get this command to work

Comment: gswin64 -dQUIET -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dDUPLEX -sDEVICE=ps2write -sOutputFile=gmsnewpostscriptdup.ps gmstestfile.ps -c "<</PSDocOptions (<</ManualFeed false>> setpagedevice statusdict begin 0 setpapertray end)>> setdistillerparams" -f

Comment: Unfortunately, unless I do a great deal of studying none of it is going to make any sense to me, and nothing in that command does what I need it to do, because I don't understand what it does in the first place.

Comment: The DUplex control should exit in the incoming PostScript, it'll almost certainly be something like "<</Duplex true>> setpagedevice" and may include "<</Tumble true>>" depending on how the duplexing unit works. Essentially you can just copy that wholesale form a working input file. Where you have a file with multiple 'setpagdevice' calls with multiple key/value pairs, you can squash them to one call, with a single dictionary (<<...>>) containing all the required pairs.